# Swift library binding to .NET MAUI project

Tags: c#, swift, maui

We have a Swift library that will help us interact with External BLE devices, We may need to use this library in .NET MAUI. To use this library, we may need to convert it to DLL.

The challenge is all the Swift classes in the Swift library are inheriting from the NSObject class, which is forcing us to add Xamarin.ios DLL as a dependency in the .NET MAUI project. This is causing conflict errors with Microsoft.ios DLL.

- How to use Xamarin.ios DLL in .NET MAUI project and fix conflicts.
- Any alternative way to reuse the existing Swift library in the .NET MAUI project.

Comment: How are you converting your Swift Library to .Net Maui?

Comment: @FreakyAli Import swift code to objective-c and binding static library in Xamarin

Comment: Are you following this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oibfI-ZsmzQ?

Comment: https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2017/09/17/objective-c-library-binding-for-xamarin-ios/

Comment: we followed this article.

Comment: Thanks, ruffin and freakyAli. we are able to resolve the issue. we referred to this link https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are able solve the issue using this link
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7755#issuecomment-1249691915